# Are high search engine hits to questions marked as duplicates ever analysed?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, closed-questions

Following on from Jeff Atwood's article:

> [Dr. Strangedupe: Or, How I Learned to Stop Worrying And Love Duplication](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/)

Do the team ever analyse hits from Google Search on questions marked as duplicates (i.e. where a duplicate is about to hit its required number of close votes, say three or four but not yet closed) and compare the hits from google on the questions being pointed to as "duplicate of"?

If a question flagged as duplicate, but not yet closed, was taking substantially more hits than the questions that are suggested as being "duplicates of", would any action be taken to clear the close votes?

Do closed questions make it into the Google sitemap?

Answer (score 2):

Closed question does not mean deleted question. So yes they are still visible for google. The community would certainly not be happy if their close vote were deleted for search engine visibility reason. I know SEO is important but user experience should stay at the top of all priorities.